# What is the best way to handle user statistics in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, caching, statistics

How would I handle user statistics in PHP?

There are two obvious methods that I can choose. Both have their flaws.

- Select MySQL COUNTs when necessary. The flaw here is that if you have many rows to count then it may be slow especially when you have to do it on seemingly every page load. The benefit is that the count will always be correct.
- Store user statistics in a statistics table. The flaw here is that you have to continuously update it whenever a change is made, and this makes code overly complicated if you need to update in bulk. The benefit is that it will be fast to select a single row of stats for a user as opposed to performing counts.

Another possible method that I'm a bit "eh" about is storing a job in a queue (and have Laravel handle it). These jobs will update the statistics necessary using other tables so that it's synchronised properly. The benefit is that it takes the load off of the web server and the flaw is that a user may get incorrect statistics. It is not desirable for *your* own friends list to say there is for example, 15 friends and 7 friend requests when the actual numbers vary greatly.

I've put into detail the methods I have come up with and I'm not sure what's best in terms of giving correct results for the user, as well as balancing speed and simplicity. If I'm doing the COUNT method then potentially I could cache the result and remove the cache record if the statistics are to be updated but I'd imagine storing a row in the cache table for EACH user is a bit overkill. Maybe this isn't really a problem as long as the database has enough space but surely searching through a massive cache table is going to be slow anyway?

Maybe someone can give me the best choice to handle user statistics. My head is spinning as it's over-thinking everything and I need to be put on the straight and narrow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Don't exaggerate the cost of `COUNT(*)` as you plan this part of your app. If you have the correct index on your table, row counting is very quick. In fact, in if your table is MyISAM it can be O(1) in complexity.

For example, if you have an index on `user` the query `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM friend WHERE user = 'mickey@disney.com'` will be very fast.

Build your app the easy way. When you have ten thousand users, you can rework this kind of statistical computation to be more elaborate and efficient. When you have more users, it will not be as obvious if you present approximate results.

Be careful, though. COUNT(*) is much faster than COUNT(expression) in most cases. The * allows MySQL to avoid evaluating every row.